# Defining a new node shape for an arrow with text

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to improve my tikz node handling. I very often use this:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex] (1,0)+(0,-1.5mm)--+(0,1.5mm)+(0,0)--+(5mm,0) node[below]{$y_1$};
\draw [thick,-latex] (0,0)+(-1.5mm,0)--+(1.5mm,0)+(0,0)--+(0,5mm) node[right]{$y_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results to

[image]

Instead of drawing this arrow completely each time I would like to define a tikz node and use it as follows:

```latex
\node[coordinate_arrow] at (1,0){$y_1$};
% rotated arrow with non rotated label
\node[coordinate_arrow, rotate=90] at (0,0){$y_1$};
```

---

My first approach was:

```
\tikzset{
  coordinate_arrow/.style={
        execute at begin node={
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[thick] (0,-1.5mm)--(0,1.5mm);
                \draw[thick, -latex] (0,0)--(5mm,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        },
    }
}
```

But here the alignment does not fit (have to be the crossing point or arrow root) and the label is not at the same place.

---

How to do it right?

---

---

Following your suggestion, I implement this using `tikzset`

```
\tikzset{
    pics/coordinate_arrow/.style = {
        code={
            \pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrot}{atan2(\tmpd,\tmpc)}
            \draw[thick, -latex] (0,-1.5mm)--(0,1.5mm) 
                (0,0)--(5mm,0)node[anchor=\myrot]{#1};
        }
    }
}
```

and can use it now in this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) pic[rotate=90]{coordinate_arrow={$y_1$}};
    \draw (0,1) pic[rotate=45]{coordinate_arrow={$y_2$}};
    \draw (1,1) pic[rotate=270]{coordinate_arrow={$y_3$}};
    \draw (1,0) pic{coordinate_arrow={$y_4$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: Look up \pdfdecalreshape (page 1142).  The hard part will be NOT rotating the text with the rest of the node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not to use your approach since it nests `tikzpicture` environments. Rather, use a `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/marrow/.style={code={
  \pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrot}{atan2(\tmpd,\tmpc)}
  \draw[thick, -latex] (0,-1.5mm)--(0,1.5mm) 
      (0,0)--(5mm,0)node[anchor=\myrot]{#1};}}]
%
 \path (0,0) pic[rotate=90]{marrow={$y_1$}} (1,0) pic{marrow={$y_1$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Man, this cat is too smart! Schrödinger had better keep him/her alive!